# How to Merge multiple Observables with diferents call backs into one single Stream?

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-kotlin

I have this problem. I'm trying to sync a local database into my android app with a remote app. I'm creating the logic to upload the new info created locally and the server responds with the remote id save it in the server. To archive this, I'm using a method that takes an array of objects an return an Observable which emit the response of the server for each element.
Like this.

```
val dailyEntries = App.db.dailyEntryDao().getDailyEntriesCreated()
            dailyEntries.sync(context) //Return an observable
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe({                        
                        val response = DailyEntry(it)//Creates a daily entry using 
                                                      the response from the server
                        thread {                                
                          App.db.dailyEntryDao().update(response)
                        }
                    }, {
                        it.printStackTrace()
                    }, {
                        uploadEnclosures()
                    })
```

How you can see, in the onSuccess from the current observable calls another method. It uses the same logic and is showing ahead.

```
private fun uploadEnclosures() {
        thread {
            val enclosures = App.db.enclosureDao().getEnclosuresCreated()
            enclosures.sync(context)
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe({
                        val response = Enclosure(it)
                        thread {                                
                            App.db.enclosureDao().update(response)
                        }
                    }, {
                        it.printStackTrace()
                    }, {
                        uploadSmokeTest()
                    })
        }
    }
```

It goes on with all the tables. Always we perform the update of the next table in the onSuccess of the current Observable. It is done like this because i need to make the sync in a specific order.

My question is, Is there a way to merge all these Observables in just one to perform a single Subscribe and controlling each onNext emotion?

Thanks for the answers

Comment: `thread {`? Starting background threads inside RxJava subscribers? Then what's `observeOn()` and `subscribeOn()` for?

Comment: That is because val enclosures = App.... retrieve info from a room table. Observe on is useful in MainThread in case I want to notify de UI any changes. Do you recommend any changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well yes, but there would be a small bit of work required, you can use `concat` operator which takes care of the ordering for you and pass it a list of `observables` in order and then subscribe to it using a single observer which expects `Any` event to trickle down to it.

To be strict on type safety you can mark your observable source types with a common interface and use instance check to take actions specific to the event type.

Check more [here](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/concat.html)

Code example -

```
fun concatCalls(): Observable<Any> {
    return Observable.concat(src1, src2, ...)
}
```

The consumer would look like this then -

```
concatCalls().subscribe(object: Subscriber<Any> {
    override fun onNext(o: Any) {
       when (o) {
           is Object1 -> // do handling for stuff emitted by src1
           is Object2 -> // do handling for stuff emitted by src2
           ....
           else // skip
    }
    ....
})
```

Comment: Being honest I don't see how to do it xD, can you post an example plz? Also, I was wondering I can implement in each Observable the doOnNext method an in that way each method knows the type of the callback. What do you think with that?

Comment: Tnx for the answer, I'm gonna implement it and see what happens. :D

Comment: hey @JhonFredyTrujilloOrtega if this helped, could you please accept the answer?